# What should I use on my Flutter Widget: `ValueKey` or `Key`

Tags: flutter, widget

I came across this scenario this week again.

I've been using `key: ValueKey(*aValue*)` but for no special reason, taking into consideration that probably using `key: Key(*aValue*)` could work similarly.

Any top reason or something for a deep understanding of using which in any case?

Answer (score 5):

The `Key` class is used to uniquely identify a widget in the widget tree. The `ValueKey` subclass of `Key` is used when the key needs to be based on the value of an object rather than the object identity itself.

In general, it is recommended to use `ValueKey` when the key needs to be based on the value of an object. This is because `ValueKey` uses the object's `hashCode` and `==` methods to determine the key, which ensures that the key remains the same even if the object itself is recreated with different attributes. This is important for cases where the widget tree needs to be rebuilt due to state changes, because using `ValueKey` ensures that the corresponding widgets are updated correctly.

On the other hand, if the key only needs to be based on the object's identity, then using `Key` would be sufficient. This is typically the case when creating a new widget that has a different state than the previous widget.

In summary, use `ValueKey` when the key needs to be based on the value of an object, and use `Key` when the key only needs to be based on the object's identity.

Answer (score 5):

```
myMillionListOfProduct = [
Product(name:soap, price: 10.00),
Product(name:butter, price: 12.00),
...
];
```

its ok if you want to write different `Key` manually, but if you want to create it *dynamically*, then there is some problem :

we can use `Key` like this:

```
products.map(product) => ProductWidget(key: Key(product.name),product: product);
```

but `Key` only accept `String`, what if there is product with same name and different on price? dart not happy and telling you : "duplicate of key".

then to make dart happy we can use the `ValueKey` :

```
products.map(product) => ProductWidget(key: ValueKey<Product>(product),product: product);
```

maybe some guy create a difference in their reference and add to our `myMillionListOfProduct`.

```
final someguysoap = Product(name:soap,price:10.00).
myMillionListOfProduct.add(someguysoap);
```

BUT, again there is one product with same value, `Product(name: soap, price: 10.00)`, using `ValueKey` will make dart not happy again.

then we use `ObjectKey` instead.

```
myMillionListOfProduct = [
Product(name:soap, price: 10.00),
Product(name:butter, price: 12.00),
someguysoap,
...
];

products.map(product) => ProductWidget(key: ObjectKey(product),product: product);
```

what if this guy add 1 more of his product with same reference?

```
myMillionListOfProduct = [
Product(name:soap, price: 10.00),
Product(name:butter, price: 12.00),
someguysoap,
someguysoap,
...
];
```

then dart will tell you that the widgets have the same objectKey. if you want this to happen,

use `UniqueKey` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`Key` is abstract class so you can't initiate it directly. There are few classes which inherits key.

- LocalKey (Another abstract class which extends Key). You can't initiate it directly as well. LocalKey is a key which is not global.
- UniqueKey - Local key used when you want to rebuild a widget everytime there is build called).
- ObjectKey - Local key used to identify items based on object which was passed. It uses identity comparison to see if keys are equals. So if between builds if object reference is same, keys will be same. If they have different reference, build method will be called.
- ValueKey (Local key used to identify different items based on their Value in widgets which has similar type of children like List/Row/Column). You can pass item.id as valueKey or entire item.It becomes more important if children are stateful widgets.
- GlobalKey (A key that is unique across entire app). It should not be re-created every build. You can't have same GlobalKey with more than one widget which leads to collision.
- LabeledGlobalKey - Global key with debug level.
- GlobalObjectKey - Same as ObjectKey but at global level. Hence you can access it anywhere.

Comment: You're mistaken. The `Key` class is abstract, yes. But there is a [factory constructor](https://www.flutterclutter.dev/flutter/basics/2023-03-19-what-are-factory-constructors/) that shadows the default constructor: `const factory Key(String value) = ValueKey<String>;`. So `const Key key = Key('myKey');` is a totally valid statement.

Comment: I think using a subclass in parent class is not a great design. But again, who am I to question others design decisions. As far as I am concerned, I like things to go in one direction from subclass to parent not other way around.

Comment: I'm just commenting on your statement "`Key` is abstract class so you can't initiate it directly" which is not correct. I am not voting for or against the design decisions of the Flutter team.

Comment: https://dart.dev/language/classes#abstract-classes As per this, you can't initiate it but it appears to be initiated. If you still believe Key class object is initiated, try printing key.runtimeType after factory statement.

Comment: Well, you're absolutely right, I'm sorry. Although for the caller it seems that one is instantiating a `Key`, in reality it's redirecting to the `ValueKey` constructor, making the runtime type `ValueKey<String>`.